# how can compare file .csproj vs latest version in source control(Visual Studio and TFS)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

Is it possible compare file .csproj vs latest version in Source Control?

In other file you can companies vs latest version easily by:

Right click on file select compare

[image]

But in file .csproj We don't see Compare any where. You can see image below.

[image]

Is it possible compare file .csproj vs latest version? How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can compare file .csproj vs latest version in source control(Visual Studio and TFS)

You could open the **Source Control Explorer** in the Team explorer and switch to your `.csproj` file, right click on that file, there is an option **Compare**:

[image]